# Is this valid JSON? Email address as reference type?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I'm integrating our system with a 3rd party. They sent a JSON example of what they are expecting. The JSON does not seem right to me. The users object has an email address which looks like being used as a [reference type's member name instead of value type's member name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). In other words, should it not be an array of users, and each item in array would be the users object, with "email": "example@company.com" as one of the properties?

I am going to ask them but also wanted to check here if anyone else thinks there is an issue with this JSON

```
    {
      "users": {
    “example@company.com”:    {
          "First_Name": "John",
          "Last_Name": "Doe",   
          "Member_Id": "XX9008000",
          "Mailing_Address": {
            "Street": "P O Box 111 ",
            "City": "Red City",
            "State": "CA",
            "Zip": "99999"
          }
        },
      "enrollments": [
        {
          "Student": "example@company.com",
          "Course_Ids": "369,370"
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to convert C# object to JSON. The output is always of the format, reference type's type: reference type's property/value enumeration.

```
{"users":[{"name":"john","id":"a1"},{"name":"tom","id":"a2"}]}
```

or

```
{"users":{"user1":{"name":"john","id":"a1"},"user2":{"name":"tom","id":"a1"}}}
```

But it can never be:

```
{"users":{"a1":{"name":"john"},"a2":{"name":"tom"}}}
```

Because a1 and a2 are *values* of value type `string Id`

It may be valid JSON but can it be obtained through a serialization library code? Or will I have to manually construct it?

Comment: Using an email address as a key to an object is syntactically valid for JSON. What does stand out as odd, though, are the quote characters surrounding the email address. There is also a closing curly brace missing at the end of the object.

Comment: Apart of a missing "}", it seems syntactically right. Semanticaly there is a problem, tho. If a key is plural ("users"), the expected content is an array of objects instead of a single object. With the current example there is no way to add more than one user, so, the plural looks like an error. I bet they will give you another version once you point out this observation

Comment: The missing curly brace at end was my mistake. I have edited my question. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json to convert C# object to JSON. The output is always of the format, reference type name: reference type property/value enumeration. How can email address be outputted like they want? In other words, value type value: reference type property/value enumeration. Unless I hand build the JSON

Comment: You should add that to the question... and/or reach out to the provider to verify this is a valid example. I'd expect the users part to be an array, the email address could be the top level though... and are `enrollments` related to each user or overall? I'd suspect overal since the email address wouldn't be needed there otherwise.

Comment: Maybe it's a C# thing, but I don't know what you mean by "reference type" and "value type".

Comment: I don't think these quotes are ok: `“example@company.com”`

Comment: You don't mean "Reference type's type". You mean "Reference type's member name."

Comment: thanks @RaymondChen I was wondering what to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the quote type (that should be "<..>") here-> “example@company.com”, this is a valid JSON, and a common use for this type of object.

Instead of an array of object, the structure is the id of the object, and inside it, the object.

You need a Dictionary<string, object> where the Key is probably username (= email) and the Value is the user object.

Comment: Did not know Dictionary would be serialized like this! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

To the first question

> should it not be an array of users?

this is a typical issue for varying json responses having either one or multiple elements.

To generate Json, it is good practice sticking with the so called Badger-Fish notation http://badgerfish.ning.com/ which states:

“Nested elements become nested properties” but “Multiple elements at the same level become array elements” therefore when there is one element, a property is displayed but in case of multiple elements an array is displayed".

Since there is only one "users" element and only one "enrollments" element at the same respective level, there shouldn't be any arrays declared.